# Creating a link to a certain marker on a google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dom

I've implemented a google maps store locator using this example: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

It's working fine, but I'm trying to get the list to show in an actual `ul` rather than in a drop down list. I've changed the results to show as `li`'s but I can't get the links to work.

It currently links to the selected option in the dropdown, but I want to make every `li` a link instead. This is the bit I need to change:

```
function load() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.438065, -1.823730),
    zoom: 4,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
  });
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
  locationSelect.onchange = function() {
    var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    if (markerNum != "none"){
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
    }
  };
}

function searchLocations() {
 var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
 var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
 geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
   } else {
     alert(address + ' not found');
   }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you can add click event on all li items and pass marker number in that click event like this:

```
function selectMarker(markerNum) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
};
```

This selectMarker function must be apply to all li for making it work.

Comment: This seems to be what I need, could you put it in to some more context or help me implement it to my code??

Comment: Well i surely can but i don't know what you want to build. As per your question I think I have already provided solution. You can ask me question if any

Comment: I've updated my question with a bit more of the code, I'm trying to create a store locator, like the example link. I want to link each of the results in the list to the correct marker, at the moment it only has the code for a change in a dropdown rather than a click on an li

Comment: How you are populating li? As it's not included in your code.

Comment: from a php file(which generates the xml) with a url like test.co.uk/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=50&lng=20&radius=200